# Rutas dinámicas con Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt

Estoy tratando de crear unas páginas con rutas dinámicas en Nuxt y no me funciona. Tengo un archivo de datos con distintas terapias. Este es el archivo portfoli.js y quiero crear las rutas con la id de las distintas terapias.

```
export default {
  inici: {
    titolEsquerra: "Espacio",
    titolDreta: "Zen",
    subtitol: "",
    nom: "Sant Joan de Moro",
    ofici: "Castellón de la Plana",
    imagen: "logo.png",
  },
  hola: {
    presentHola: "Terapias,",
    presentSoy: "Masajes",
    presentNom: "Cursos ",
    presentOfici: "y mucho más.",
  },
index:{
    llista: [
      {
        titol:'Terapias.',
        enlace:'/terapias',
        id:'terapias',
        projectes:[
          {
            titol:'Reiki.',
            text:'El Reiki es una técnica de sanación natural que se basa en la transferencia de energía a través de las manos. Se originó en Japón a principios del siglo XX y se utiliza para equilibrar el flujo energético del cuerpo, lo que puede ayudar a mejorar la salud física, mental y emocional.',
            enlace:"#",
            id:"reiki",
            imagen:[
              'reiki.png',
            ]

          },
          {
            titol:'Psicoterapia de UCDM.',
            text:'La Psicoterapia de UCDM utiliza la meditación, la oración y el diálogo terapéutico para ayudar a los pacientes a encontrar su verdadera identidad como seres espirituales, a aceptarse a sí mismos y a los demás, y a superar sus miedos y limitaciones. La terapia también enfatiza la importancia de vivir en el presente y la responsabilidad personal de nuestras emociones y experiencias.',
            enlace:'#',
            id:"ucdm",
            imagen:[
              'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/27/08/45/stone-lotus-4972881__340.jpg',
            ]

          },
          {
            titol:'Tethahealing.',
            text:'ThetaHealing es una técnica de meditación desarrollada por Vianna Stibal en 1994, técnica diseñada para ayudar a las personas a rectificar creencias limitantes de la mente subconsciente a través de la frecuencia cerebral theta, mejorando la calidad de vida en todos los aspectos.',
            enlace:'#',
            id:"theta",
            imagen:[
              'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/27/08/45/stone-lotus-4972881__340.jpg',
            ]

          },
]}
]}
}
```

Este es el archivo index.vue que se encuentra dentro de una carpeta llamada terapias que esta dentro de pages. Aqui salen todas las terapias tipo blog y cada una tiene un enlace para entrar en la página individual de la terapia.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <h1>Terapias</h1>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-col
            md="6"
            v-for="(element, indexServeis) in serveis"
            :key="indexServeis"
          >
            <div v-for="(producte, i) in element.projectes" :key="i">
              <nuxt-link :to="'/terapias/' + producte.id">
                <h2>{{ producte.titol }}</h2>
              </nuxt-link>
                <div v-for="(img, indeximg) in producte.imagen" :key="indeximg">                  
                <v-img :src="img">                  
                </v-img>
                </div>
                <div style="padding: 30px; font-weight: 900">
                    {{ producte.text }}
                  </div>
            </div>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import portfoli from "@/dades/portfoli";

export default {
  mounted() {
    this.portfoliVue = portfoli;
    this.serveis = this.portfoliVue.index.llista;
  },
  data() {
    return {
      serveis: false,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Hasta aquí todo correcto, lo que no logro es crear la página para cada terapia de manera individual. Aqui muestro el archivo _id.vue que debería hacer eso, No consigo que salga el título de la terapia.

```
   <template>
  <v-container>
      <v-row>
          <v-col>
              <h1>{{blog.titol}}</h1>
          </v-col>
      </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import portfoli from "@/dades/portfoli";

export default {
  mounted() {
    this.portfoliVue = portfoli;
    this.blog = this.portfoliVue.index.llista;
    let identificador = this.$route.params.id;
            //console.log(identificador)

            this.blog.forEach(producte=>{
              console.log(producte);
              this.producte.projectes.forEach(terapies =>{
                if(identificador == terapies.id){
                    // L'hem trobat
                    this.blog = producte
                }
              })
            })
  },
  data() {
    return {
      blog:false,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabo de resolverlo, no se muy bien cómo ni la causa.
En el archivo _id.vue que es el que se ocupa de las rutas dinámicas.
He eliminado la variable this.blog y he realizado el bucle forEach directamente en la ruta donde se encuentra el array, dando como resultado, ahora si, una variable llamada blog con los objetos del array projectes. Para pasar esta variable a mi html lo tengo que hacer a través del data y aquí le doy el valor de un objeto vacío. Quedaria asi:

```
<script>
import portfoli from "@/dades/portfoli";

export default {
  mounted() {
    this.portfoliVue = portfoli;
    let identificador = this.$route.params.id;

    this.portfoliVue.index.llista.forEach((categoria) => {
      categoria.projectes.forEach((terapia) => {
        if (terapia.id === identificador) {
          this.blog = terapia;
        }
      });
    });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      blog: {},
    };
  },
};
</script>
```